# Spinner Item re-selected

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I am implementing a spinner with auto fill text view and adding same list in adapter of Spinner and auto fill text view,
If I select a item from spinner it will be set in autoFillTextView,
But the problem is if I select a item from spinner and then make a change in autofillTextView, and then again select same item from spinner then controller is not going back to spinner onSelected method,

Thanks in advance.

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
switch (parent.getId()) {
    case R.id.spinnerGroupName:
        actvMatchGroup.setText("");
        //Your Another Action Here.
        for (int i = 0; i < groupList.size(); i++) {
            if (groupName[position] == groupList.get(i).getGroupName())     {
                groupId = Integer.parseInt(groupList.get(i).getGroupId());
                group_id = groupId;
            }
        }
        tvMatchGroup.setText(groupName[position]);
        actvMatchGroup.setText(groupName[position]);
    break;
}
```

Comment: So what is it that you want help with? It isn't very clear what you want here, please add the details.

Comment: spinner re-select option do nothing, Is there any method like onReselctItem(){} in spinner,